# Force label repetitions for nodes in geom_node_text in ggraph

Tags: r, ggraph

I am having some trouble forcing the labels I want in `ggraph`. I have a data frame for edges, another one for nodes that look like this:

```
> edges
# A tibble: 160 × 2
   Elec1n Elec2n
    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      1     45
 2      1     44
 3      1     42
 4      1     41
 5      1     34
 6      2     50
 7      2     49
 8      2     40
 9      2     39
10      2     35
# … with 150 more rows

> nodes
# A tibble: 52 × 6
   group label degrees family order  elec
   <chr> <fct>   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1     Fp1_1       5 fronp      1     1
 2 1     Fp2_1       9 fronp      2     2
 3 1     F7_1        6 fron       3     3
 4 1     F3_1        7 fron       4     4
 5 1     Fz_1       11 fron       5     5
 6 1     F4_1        9 fron       6     6
 7 1     F8_1       11 fron       7     7
 8 1     FC5_1       8 fronc      8     8
 9 1     FC1_1       6 fronc      9     9
10 1     FC2_1       4 fronc     10    10
# … with 42 more rows
```

As it can be seen, I reordered because I wanted certain electrodes to be ordered in a certain way, frontal electrodes up, and coming down with the same logic at both sides. There are other intentional dummy variables also to separate both sides. At the end, I will have 25 electrodes connecting to other 25 electrodes in the other side, and using graph and the labels out of the nodes data frame I have the following:

```
      elec <- nodes$label
      net.tidy <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes, edges = edges, directed = TRUE, node_key = "label")
      
      plt <- ggraph(net.tidy, layout = 'linear', circular = TRUE) +
        ggtitle("Circular network plot of ") +
        geom_edge_arc(aes(color = edge_family),alpha = 0.5) + 
        scale_edge_colour_manual(values = paletteE) +
        scale_edge_width(range = c(0.2, 2)) +
        scale_colour_manual(values= palette) +
        geom_node_point(aes(size = degrees, color = family)) +
        coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + 
        theme_graph(base_family = 'Helvetica') +
        theme(legend.position = "right") 
put <- plt +
        geom_node_text(aes(label = elec), size = 4,  nudge_x = plt$data$x * .15, nudge_y = plt$data$y * .15, check_overlap=FALSE)
      plt
```

This, with other code I am not getting into, gives me the following plot:[image]

My concern here is I don't understand why `geom_node_text(aes(label = elec)` is not working and taking the labels to the nodes and it still uses the numeration of the electrodes instead of its names.

Do anybody know why this could be happening? Does anybody know why I can't force the labels into the `geom_node_text`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't provided a complete reproducible example, which makes checking your code quite difficult. Where is "edge_family" defined? I wonder if the elec variable you define is being overwritten by the elec column name in the nodes tibble.

Comment: There is a bunch of other code I thought was unnecessary for the question. However, your point is pretty clever. I wasn't thinking on this detail and it is in fact important. I've just checked it and you are right, the fact that they are sharing the same name is an issue, I was not thinking on that. I changed ```elec``` to ```elec2``` and confirmed you made target, thank you!